# Manual authentication with spring security and remember me provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to implement a manual login process. The authentication works fine:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
```

But how can I use remember me provider in this case? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is the following:

1. Check user's password
2. Authorize user:

   ```
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
   token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));                        
   Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
   ```
3. Autowire `rememberMeService` and call:

`rememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(request, response, authenticatedUser);`

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer . it worked for me.

with new version of spring security :

```
RememberMeAuthenticationToken auth = new RememberMeAuthenticationToken("your key",userDetails,  autorities);
            String  p = request.getParameter("rememberme");
    //      your request need this parameter

            Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
            myrememberMeService.loginSuccess(request, response, authenticatedUser);
```